# Does existence of a bijection between $2$ different sets implies that they have the same cardinality?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f$ be our bijection from $A$ to $B$.

$$f: A \to B$$

For it to be a bijection, each element in $A$ must be mapped to a different element in $B$; and each element in $B$ must correspond to at least one element in $A$ by the definition. So therefore it must be true that,

$$s(A) = s(B).$$

But what if they are of infinite cardinality?

Comment: Yes.  In fact, that is the definition of "same cardinality" in case of infinite sets.  Defining the concept "same cardinality" is easier than defining the concept of "cardinal number".  But whatever a cardinal number is, it should correspond to this notion of "same cardinality".

Comment: Yes. Read Georg Cantor or Wacław Sierpiński.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This comment is a full answer:

> Yes. In fact, that is the definition of "same cardinality" in case of infinite sets. Defining the concept "same cardinality" is easier than defining the concept of "cardinal number". But whatever a cardinal number is, it should correspond to this notion of "same cardinality". – GEdgar

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to prove that no bijection is possible if A is finite and B is infinite. Thus you have that if a bijection dose exists then either A and B are finite or both are infinite.
If the sets are finite the existence of a bijection imply that they have the same number of elements. If the sets are infinite then **by definition** the have the same cardinality.